# Set gridview row with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, gridview

I have a table that has a class name partnerGridClass.
I would like to set one of the rows background colors that corresponds to a certain index n.  n is just a javascript variable.

```
$("table.partnerGridClass tbody tr:nth-child(n)").css("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
```

What I have above is not working for selecting the nth row.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("table.partnerGridClass tbody tr:nth-child("+n+")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the 'n' obviously must be substituted with the actual number.  So if n is a variable, you need to write:

```
$("table.partnerGridClass tbody tr:nth-child(" + n + ")").css("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
```

Even then, keep in mind that it starts at 1, so if n=0 is the first, you'd need to add one to it first.